# Editable cells formatting in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and [bootstrap-table-editable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-editable) to have editable cells. If cell is stringified json, editable cell isn't formatted correctly (as a string).

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0oehnzk2/1/)

**html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="name" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true" data-editable="true">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true" data-editable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

var data = [{name: 'John', stargazers_count: 232, forks_count: 214, description: "{x:5,y:6}"},
           {name: 'Craig', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 224, description: "{x:5,y:6}"},
           {name: 'Barry', stargazers_count: 238, forks_count: 234, description: "{x:5,y:6}"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data,
    sortable: true,
    editable: true
});
```

Cells of last column are formatted as *[object Object]*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1819) on Github, where is solution.